# Expression<Func<T,bool>> adds an unwanted Convert when created in generic method

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda, expression-trees

I have a function to generate an expression to be used in a linq Where clause.

```
public static Expression<Func<T,bool>> GetWhereCondition<T>() where T : IActive
{
    return x => x.Active;
}
```

(note IActive only defines the property 'Active')

There are other related functions and the idea is that i can inject the required conditions into a Generic class to control business rules, etc.

The problem is that when I run this, the returned Expression contains the lamda (seen from the debugger):

```
x => Convert(x).Active
```

Which is of course rejected by linq:
'LINQ to Entities only supports casting Entity Data Model primitive types.'

SO my question is...

How do I prevent this behaviour. There is no need for a conversion and clearly it is undesireable. Is it even possible to prevent this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, assuming this only needs to work with classes (the conversion is for boxing value-types), you can add a `class` constraint:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetWhereCondition<T>() where T : class, IActive
{
    return x => x.Active;
}
```

...and the conversion goes away.

Comment: ah, interesting; the fundamental difference there is the change between "constrained" to "callvirt"; it is interesting that this lets it work

Comment: I spent an entire day trying to fix the same issue. In the end, I wrote an ExpressionVisitor to remove the convert call manually, which worked. In the end, I simply needed to add a class constraint to the interface type constraint

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> GetWhereCondition<T>() where T : IActive
{
    return x => x.Active;
}
```